# Applications are crashing

Tags: nautilus, crash

for a few days ago my applications are started to crash in ubuntu 14.04. I open nautilus, hit CTRL+H and nautilus crashes, open bittorrent client and when I want to delete one of my torrent files, the client crashes and other (not all) applications crashes the same way. I upgraded ubuntu to 14.10 but nothing changed. When I open nautilus in terminal, and the application crashes:
fish: Job 1, "nautilus" terminated by signal SIGSEGV (Address boundary error)

and in the same time all dropdows are broken, when I clic them, application crash..

[image: all dropdowns]

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Your hard drive might be failing. Back in october, I dropped my laptop. I thought it was fine, so I did nothing, but it turned out that my hdd was failing. This is exactly what happened. You can test it using this tool: http://www.seagate.com/support/downloads/seatools/
Make sure you don't move your mouse after you start the testing.

Comment: yeah SIGSEGV means that you have a memory access error. But this much more often in the RAM.

Comment: Will edit To include memtest

Comment: the seatools - all OK, Linux disk utility - disk is OK, 23 bad sectors, in terminal: sudo badblocks - O errors, other tests all went OK, memtest also looking good